# Is it safe to pass filename in GET?

Tags: php, html, security, web

I am doing

```
index.php?letter=1&show=cat.jpg
```

File I do not include, but use it only as `<img src="$_GET['show']">`

Is it safe?

Comment: Passing filename is safe, but the way you are handling it at server side is not safe.

Comment: `index.php?letter=1&show=/some/protected/folder/somefile`

Comment: I do not include it. I use <img ..> It is loaded via brouser, not by server. If user do not have access, than such requiest will fail, isn't it?

Comment: sure it will fail if have no access. but your image will be broken.

Comment: well, yes. If user manually edit the query and it showed nothing it is fine. What about security issue to load protected files?

Comment: @bansi Your concern is related only to including stuff server side. In this case the server is tasked only with generating a request markup which will be executed by the client (browser). Even if the show parameter gets manipulated to access a protected resource that would not be any different from making a direct request unless the image folder is above DocumentRoot.

Comment: You have to take care of xss attacks. Passing `show=/some/protected/folder/somefile` won't make any security issues. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Its safe to use. But you want to take care of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.
Actually now you are showing the content attached to your parameter `show` inside your html page. Think a scenario if a user edited the  'cat.jpg' and inserted some script content into it.

See [this](http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/67148385214/a-simple-xss-demo-on-times-of-india) simple [example](http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/67148385214/a-simple-xss-demo-on-times-of-india) by [Arjun Sreedharan](http://arjunsreedharan.org/).

XSS attack to your url would be as shown below

```
index.php?letter=1&show=Path/To/some/other/Image"></img><h1>XSS Attack</h1><div> Showing False data in your website</div><img src="Some/Other/Image.jpg
```

The Html rendered in your page would be

```
<img src="Path/To/some/other/Image"></img>
<h1>XSS Attack</h1>
<div> Showing False data in your website</div>
<img src="Some/Other/Image.jpg">
```

The solution is to encode html. [HtmlEntities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in PHP.

Comment: Try this url on your website. index.php?letter=1&show=Path/To/some/other/Image"></img><h1>XSS Attack</h1><div> Showing False data in your website</div>

Answer (score 2):

Simple code to validate the input.

```
// Check File Param provided
$filename  = (isset($_GET['show']) ? $_GET['show'] : '');
if (strlen($filename) == 0) {
    die('File Not Provided');
}

// remove leading '/' or double slashes (will also hack out http:// injections)
$filename = trim($filename);
$filename = str_replace('//', '/', $filename);
while (strlen($filename) > 0 && strcmp(substr($filename,0,1), '/') == 0) {
    $filename = substr($filename, 1);
}

// Check filename exists
if (file_exists('./' . $filename)) {  // Note the "./", also will to prevent cross site injections; if using a sub-directory, add in here
    die ('file does not exist');
}

// Check file actually is an image
if (!@getImageSize('./' . $filename)) {
    die ('file is not an image');
}

// Should be safe at this point.
```

You could also preg_match for a pattern if you know the pattern of filename e.g. always expecting a .png).

You probably also want to handle errors differently, but this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe but the mechanism to deliver/show that file should be proper to handle only authorized requests.

If you want then you can do it by POST, but some time its possessive when you refresh the page and browser asking to confirm that previously posted data sends back to server again.

Above are my personal view.

Comment: " but the mechanism to deliver/show that file should be proper to handle only authorized requests"
What is this? It is fine, when pictures just lay in one folder? I do not care, if this img folder will be accessable. I want the nobody had access to scripts.

Comment: Please read this. So that you can understand what did he mean. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: @Tigran You said that image folder accessible and nobody access script. What is it?

I mean to say that when you pass file name in get then, the `PHP` file which going to execute should have proper mechanism so that unwanted users can not access it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say get something like `image_id` from URL and then retrieve the relevant data from database and output your own data (e.g. file name) in the markup.

Even if you consider different ways of validating or filtering the users' input, you might still be open to some attacks or maybe bugs. To avoid that, again, I'd recommend to get a `key` from user and then based on that key output the data. Validating that key is much easier and also you are not gonna to output it again -- you're using that only in the back-end so it won't be a security hole for XSS attacks for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo basename(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\.-]/i','',$_GET['show'])); ?>">
```

This will this will only return name of a file even if path or url is passed.